# How to execute mysql query with LIKE statement in Django

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I am trying to search in my `mysql` database with `LIKE` statement :

```
indexstr = request.GET['index']
indexstr = '%' + indexstr + '%'
offset = int(request.GET['offset'])
for row_data in advertisement.objects.raw(
        'select * from requests_advertisement WHERE short_description LIKE '    + indexstr + ' LIMIT 10 OFFSET ' + str(offset*5)):
```

But it has this error: 
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8y5Rk.png)

It seems that it cannot work with `%` character. When I remove `%` it works correctly.

Comment: The code executing and "working correctly" are two different things. Don't use string concatenation to build your queries, it's an SQL injection risk.

Comment: I don't know the exact setups here, but something like `cursor.execute("""select * from requests_advertisement WHERE short_description LIKE %s""",  ('%' + indexstr + '%',))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to use a raw query here. You need the `__icontains` lookup:

```
advertisement.objects.filter(short_description__icontains=request.GET["index"])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,it worked ;-), does it have a same performance and speed as a query with like statement.and what about "match() against() query" ?